# PHP file uploading script not uploading files

Tags: php, file-upload

I have this code to upload multiple files.

I'm able to browse and select files but not able to upload to the specified folder.

```
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
          Browse <input name="upload[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
</span>

    <!-- processing the selected files -->

<?php
for($i=0; $i<count($_FILES['upload']['name']); $i++) {

//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];    

if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
  //Setup our new file path
  $newFilePath = "./uploadedFiles/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

  //move to new path
  move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath) ;
}
}
?>
```

What is wrong here ?

Comment: do you have a form..???

Comment: Did you get any errors, what were they etc? Pasting code and ask what is wrong isn't going to get you much help...

Comment: I didn't get any error. Just the files aren't getting uploaded. @skywalker

Comment: I don't have a form. @TintuCRaju

Comment: @Gissipi_453 i think that was your problem. Please check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be you missed **enctype** on your from

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

As most of the people forget it.